# what is the name of this yellow component in the motherboard?

Tags: components

I am not an electrician and I have no idea what is the name of this part on the image.

[image]

It makes a strange high frequency noise and I suspect thet the fault of this item causes my tv not to turn on. It has the following text written on its side:

MSC TY-T0129 122103

The tv is logik l22fed12. Is this component tv specific or can I buy a similar one? The main question is the name of the component but I would be happy if you could tell me whether I have any chance to make my tv up and running by replacing it or not.

Comment: That is a transformer. The "hum" you hear is normal. Is that why you suspect it is faulty? Have you done any other tests?

Comment: I havent done any other test cause i don't have tools for it. The noise is the reason why I thought itis faulty. It is good to know that it is normal. Thanks. you can post is as an answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probablly a transformer providing the voltage conversion and isolation needed by the power supply.

Unfortunately transformers tend to be among the less standardised parts, so finding a drop-in replacement may be difficult.

I suspect it's not actually the problem though, transformers and inductors in switch mode power supplies normally make some noise and in a broken power supply can make a hell of a lot of noise even though some other component is at fault.

Answer (score 6):

The fine wire switching power supply transformer with yellow Mylar insulation tape may be squeezing due to excessive load swings due a component wear out downstream.  E-Caps are biggest items to wear out first and the large orange e-cap is starting to show signs of internal gas pressure inside.  Replace it with a same C and V or higher but low ESR good quality (Japanese ) brand cap avail at Mouser, RS or Digi-Key